# R: Check if any value in df row is not present in same row in other df

Tags: r

I have two `data.frame()` with same number of rows but unequal number of columns:

```
df1 = data.frame(v1=c(NA,NA,2),v2=c(4,3,NA),v3=c(1,2,2))
df2 = data.frame(v4=c(NA,NA,NA), v5=c(NA,4,2))

> df1
  v1 v2 v3
1 NA  4  1
2 NA  3  2
3  2 NA  2

> df2
  v4 v5
1 NA NA
2 NA  4
3 NA  2
```

I need to check **row-wise** if there is any value in row x of df2 which is **not present** in the corresponding row in df1. I also would like to ignore `NA`.

Result should be

```
0
1
0
```

since value `4` (in `df2`, row 2) is **not present** in row 2 of `df1` (where `3`, `2` are present).

In the moment I use:

```
for (row in seq(1:nrow(df1))){
  print(as.numeric(FALSE %in% (df2[row,] %in% df1[row,])))
}
```

However, this seems to be a bad solution wrt to performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `Map/mapply` to loop over the `list`s after splitting the datasets by row (`asplit` - `MARGIN = 1`), then use `%in%` to create a logical and coerce it to binary (`+`)

```
+(mapply(\(x, y) any(!y[complete.cases(y)] %in% 
    x[complete.cases(x)]),  asplit(df1, 1), asplit(df2, 1)))
[1] 0 1 0
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting the error `Error: unexpected input in "+(mapply(\"`

Comment: @Peter probably you have an older `R` version.  change the `\(x, y)` to `function(x, y)`

Comment: Correct I'm on version 4.0.2, added `function(x,y)` and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

```r
for (row in 1:nrow(df1)){
  print(as.numeric(any(!df2[row,] %in% df1[row,], na.rm = T)))
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).